# How to define a preffered (in the sense of main, default) child object in a one to many in Grails?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, one-to-many, grails-domain-class

Consider the following domain class

```
class Person {

    String fullName

    static hasMany = [
            emails: EmailAddress
    ]

    EmailAddress defaultEmailAddress
}
```

and its corresponding

```
class EmailAddress {

    String email

    static belongsTo = [person: Person]

    static constraints = {
        email( unique:true, email:true )
    }
}
```

It seems to me that this is the best way for a given Person to set his preferred EmailAddress. The other obvious option is to have a flag in EmailAddress indicating if it is the preferred one. But, by having a direct reference from the Person to his prefferred EmailAddress I can guarantee only one EmailAddress to be the preferred one at any given time, plus I guess it performs better.

The problem is I keep getting TransientPropertyValueException due to this defaultEmailAddress, if I remove this property then it runs just fine.

Here is my code for setting up and saving a new Person object

```
/*
  Comes from a submitted form containing (I can't use less than and greater than in SO so I used parenthesis...).
  (input type="text" name="fullName" value="Full Name" /)
  (input type="text" name="emails[0].email" value="test@email.com" /)
*/
Person person = new Person( params );
person.defaultEmailAddress = person.emails[0];
person.save( flush:true );
```

I think I get a TransientPropertyValueException due to the backreference from defaultEmailAddress to Person, when constructing the Person grails automatically defines the backreference for person.emails[0], but when I explicitly set

```
person.defaultEmailAddress = person.emails[0];
```

then it just not works for the backreference and gives me the following output:

```
2015-09-18 18:54:36,858 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - TransientPropertyValueException occurred when processing request
Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation : sos.Person.defaultEmailAddress -> sos.EmailAddress. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation : sos.Person.defaultEmailAddress -> sos.EmailAddress
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug with Hibernate? Help please.

Answer (score 0):

I'd define the defaultEmailAddress as `hasOne` (see [ref-doc](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#manyToOneAndOneToOne)):

```
static hasOne = [ defaultEmailAddress:EmailAddress ]
```